# creando un proyecto maven-archetype-quickstar ha encontrado un problema

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Estoy creando un proyecto maven en Eclipse Mars2, java 7 y maven 3.2.5 bajo windows10; en eclipse preferences->General->Network Conecctions no tengo nada configurado 
[image: Pantalla de Conexiones]

Hasta el momento no he podido resolver este problema

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version

La configuracion de maven corre bien como se muestra, pero una consulta si tengo windows10 porque aparece windows 8.1

El apoyo a esto llevo varias semanas y no lo puedo resolver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero  que mires la configuración de tu Eclipse o tu Maven instalado manualmente  de igual forma el  java  que tienes instalado para poder compilar correctamente porque la compilación depende de la versión del java y el maven, por  otro lado puede ser que tengas configurado un setting y por ende no tengas acceso al Maven repositorio y no descargue la dependencia revisa en Windos>preferences y escribe Maven> User setting 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes asegurarte de no tener el global setting configurado porque si lo tienes posiblemente no se conecte al repositorio Maven centralizado… Por otra parte debe de mirar la configuraicon que tengas en tu lugar de trabajo posiblemente tienen deshabilitado  el acceso y debes colocar una IP que te permita tener acceso.

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Otra forma de crearlo es;**
si no te funciona puedes crear el arquetipo por la consola 
Crea un directorio  e ingre a la ubicación por la cd y coloca esta líneas de comando asegúrate de colocar esto para tu proyecto

- DgroupId=paquete
  DartifactId=nombre proyecto 
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false

Para más información revisa este link te explican mejor la configuración por CMD
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
Saludo espero te ayude

Comment: Hola Jhon, mi user setting y el Global estan por defecto no lo he configurado y como adjunte la pantalla de conexiones tampoco he colocado ningun valor porque estoy haciendo un trabajo de forma libre....tambien he realizado crear el proyecto por consola y me sale el mismo error....recuerdo anteriormente tenia instalado el windows10 de fabrica en mi laptop y creaba proyectos sin problemas; pero tuve problemas con el windows10 y lo volvi a instalar y ahora que quiero hacer un proyecto con maven tengo estos problemas tendra que ver algo lo que comento,.....gracias